# Split table in PHPPdf when site end with Symfony and Twig

Tags: php, symfony, pdf

I want created a PDF with more than one site. I have following with PHPPdf and Twig (as example):

```
<pdf>
    <dynamic-page>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>1.</td>
                <td>Some header</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>1.1</td>
                <td>Some subheader</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td> </td>
                <td>Relay long text here........</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </dynamic-page>
</pdf>
```

Now I have the problem that the table part with the long text will write in some cases (when there is not enough place on the site) completely set on the next page in the PDF. But I want that it write as much text as possible on the current page and split than the table with the following text to the next site. Is there a way to do that?